# Why did my materials become weird after I apllied the scale to my cup?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm following the donut tutorials and I made some scale modifications to my cup so it matches the real world scale. The coffee cup used to look like this (ignore the ugly spoon):
[image: Before]

When I found a scale I was happy with, I applied the scale to all elements of the cofee cup group (coffe liquid, the cup, the plate, the inner part with the droplets and the spoon) and when I turned cycles shading on it looked like this:
[image: After]

Ctrl + z won't solve it because in my despair, I loaded the file on which this is being worked on and I had already saved the applying of the scale.
How do I solve this?

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: 1) Check the direction of your normals (by enabling "face orientation" under overlays.)  2) Look for any use of object coordinates in your materials (usually, the object output of a texture coordinate node.)  Those are the two most common reasons for apparent material changes upon applying scale.

Comment: @Nathan Solved! The cup was red in the viewport when I enabled "face orientation", and I've seen in one of the guru's tutorials that it means the normals are inverted. I fiddled around with the Alt+N menu (the normals menu) and It all was solved with "Recalculate Outside".

Comment: @moonboots I should've included it in the post, shouldn't I? Sorry. I'll include the file in future posts, but it's no longer necesary since it is now solved.

Comment: @AllenSimpson yes, actually. It was the same problem. And it was fixed the same way.

Comment: Thank you guys very much for helping me with this!